# Understanding Dependency Injection - Play Java

Tags: java, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0

I am trying to understand the Dependency injection workflow for play framework.

I have the following DI code which works perfectly fine if written in å controller, but when written in a separate class, injection of configuration and mailerClient dose not instantiate the properties.

Does the DI work only in controllers for Play framework in Java?

My class which fails to work:

```
public class EmailConfig {

    @Inject MailerClient mailerClient;

    @Inject Configuration configuration;


    /**
     * 
     */
    public EmailConfig() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void sendEmail(String subjectConfigName, String toConfigName, String text, String from){
        Email email = new Email();
        email
          .setSubject(this.configuration.getString(subjectConfigName))
          .setFrom(from)
          .addTo(this.configuration.getString(toConfigName))
          .setBodyText(text);

        this.mailerClient.send(email);
    }

}
```

Any inputs are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of fw did you use?

Comment: 2.5! Does the behavior mentioned in question makes any sense to you? Or am I going something absurdly wrong here?

Comment: I just want to make sure I use the correct syntax for you. Please check my answer and let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

The controller is *automatically* injected so you can simply use `@Inject` to inject the dependency from it, while your separated class is neither *automatically* nor any *custom binding*. Thus the injection from such class should be done by explicit call to the *injector* with `Play.current().injector()` (for *Play 2.5*). Try this one:

```
private Configuration configuration = Play.current().injector().instanceOf(Configuration.class);
```